# Python PySimpleGUi suexpected behavior trying to "copy-paste" inputText

Tags: python, events, input, pysimplegui

Hello i have a small program that gets input from user, I suddenly noticed that after few uses in the program I cant use CONTROL + A / CONTROL + C /CONTROL + D the inputText doesnt respond.
if I restart the program this buttons events work.

```
layout = [[sg.Text('WELCOME', justification='center', size=(50))],
      [sg.InputText(), sg.Text(': ENTER SOME TEXT ', justification='right')],
      [sg.Button('Search', bind_return_key=True)]
      window = sg.Window('Client Connection V2.0Beta2', layout, element_justification='c')
      while True:
event, values = window.read()
user_text= values[0]

if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED :  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
    window.close()
    break
elif event == 'Search:  # First step user search for
#some Code....
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine for following code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('WELCOME', justification='center', expand_x=True)],
    [sg.Text('ENTER SOME TEXT: '), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Button('Search', bind_return_key=True)],
]

window = sg.Window('Client Connection V2.0Beta2', layout, element_justification='c')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    elif event == 'Search':
        user_text = values[0]
        print(user_text)

window.close()
```

In your description, it didn't show how about the other keyboard input.
It maybe caused by the focus not on the input element, maybe you press the TAB key by accidentally, then the focus shift to next element, 'Search` button here, then all the keyboard input will not be responded in the input element.

In following figure, button `Search` focused and with a dash box on it, and then the keyboard input to input element will be not responded.
[image]

Try to press TAB key to move focus to input element.
[image]

Comment: at the begining i thought soo too, but im sure i have my focus on the text input

Comment: There maybe something not shown in your post.

Comment: im testing it so i can take video of the situation

Comment: A video: [link](https://vimeo.com/657417685)

Comment: It looks like you input from mouse by clicking on a software-simulate keyboard ?

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong even with installed `Hot Virtual Keyboard`.

Comment: did you try after some time or few times at a row?
It very weird, because at the first try it works and after some time the app running it stops listen to "ctrl-c"/"ctrl-v"/"ctrl-a" keyboard events, press Tab or Enter works fine.

Comment: After two hours passed, couple tests during this period, still nothing wrong. I also run some other applications, like browser, python script, notepad, console, painter, file explorer, ..., during this period. It looks that I cannot help it if I cannot duplicate the issue.